# fosuserbundle issue after upload via git

Tags: git, symfony

i'm facing a situation : 
I work on a symfony 2.7 app, everything works fine on my local copy, but once I push my code to my git server, and then pull it from my web server, I get a wonderful

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 21: 
Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I have reinstalled via composer the Fosuserbundle and pulled, but nothing changed.
The cache folders are empty.

*My work copy is on my laptop, and the git server and web server (apache 2) are on a local server on my network.
Both computer are debian 8.*

Any help would be welcome !
Thanks !

**EDIT**

thought I am not used to use git, just know how i did :
created an empty folder on server, then

```
git init --bare
```

On my dev computer, i cloned the repo, then put my sources inside that new folder,

```
git add .
git commit -m"some comment"
git push
```

then on the var/www/ folder on server, i cloned the repo.

really dont know if I was supposed to do this, or if there is a more sofisticated way ... Actually I can see the code modifications, so I guess it's not that bad...

Comment: Are you sure composer installed all dependencies properly?

Comment: I guess so, because everything works fine on my local code... I've just copied the whole folder of my app to my web server, and everything works fine... I dont understand where's the git issue, thats quite weird

Comment: check if existing you FOSUserBundle vendor. And check if all vendor folder is not under git

Comment: i suppose you mean does the fosuserbundle exists and is it tracked ? the bundle exists in my copy.. But, i use git add .  does it mean that files could be / are untracked ? I suck at git :/ OK I m reading something 'bout the difference between add. and add -A, I guess my problem comes from here ! ill check that !

Comment: @singebatteur Your vendors should not be tracked... You just have to install them with `composer install` . Vendors folder should be add in your .gitignore (it's already did if you use standard symfony installation)

Comment: you 're right, my setup of git was quite messy I guess !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i understand what is the problem : usage of `add .` instead of `add -A` might not have looked at the changes in my fosbundle after re installation.

thanks  Семенихин Максим, you put me on track !

Good day !

Answer (score 0):

You can run git status to see what files are added or not

Comment: I actually did, but there was no untracked files mentionned :/ I might have done some dirty work at a moment... dont know where !